# how do i create spiral vortex with texture or by modeling

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, uv, unity

hi i need help to creating spiral vortex something like this it would be great if you help me 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a vertical edge, move it away from its origin, give it a third vertex next to the bottom. Give it a *Screw* modifier. Apply it. Give it a white material. Select the face loop that was created between bottom and second vertex and give it a second material (black). Give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier.

[image]

If you have a more complex texture pattern (example: *Image Texture*), you could just keep one segment, unwrap it, give it the texture, then duplicate on the Z axis.

[image]